# Is it possible to create a collections with Spring configuration?

Tags: java, spring, collections, inversion-of-control

Suppose I have a class `MyClass` which can be instantiated either with `String` or it have predefined static instances inside a class.

Something like this:

```
public class MyClass {

   public final static MyClass A = new MyClass("A");
   public final static MyClass B = new MyClass("B");
   public final static MyClass C = new MyClass("C");
   ...

   public MyClass(String name) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Is it possible to create an `ArrayList<MyClass>` bean in Spring config somehow? Something like

```
<bean id="sequence" class="...ArrayList"> 
    <member class="...MyClass" value="A"/>
    <member ... />
    ....
</bean>
```

**UPDATE 1**

Is it possible to write following way:

```
<bean id="sequence" class="...ArrayList"> 
  <constructor-arg>
     <list>
         <bean class="...MyClass" constructor-arg="A"/>
         <bean class="...MyClass" constructor-arg="B"/>
         <bean class="...MyClass" constructor-arg="C"/>
     </list>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Comment: I think you will find this useful : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
<bean id="myClassA" class="org.foo.MyClass"> 
   <constructor-arg>
     <bean class="java.lang.String">
       <constructor-arg value="A"/>
     </bean>   
   <constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="sequence" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="myClassA" />
            ...
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Note, however, that the most common approach is to inject a list directly into a bean rather than wrapping a list within a list first.

Comment: Is it possible to refer the element easier than full bean syntax?

Comment: Yes, the bean reference approach allows easier addition of new beans. See update.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at the [Collections](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-collection-elements) section in the spring IOC documentation.

```
<bean id="moreComplexObject" class="example.ComplexObject">
  <property name="someList">
    <list>
      <value>a list element followed by a reference</value>
      <ref bean="myDataSource" />
    </list>
  </property>    
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes.  You can even create it as a standalone bean.  See [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?10144-Does-the-XML-config-support-List-as-a-standalone-element) for two examples.