# Spring DI way to declare & Instaniate an Arraylist?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Starting out with Spring. And, I heard someone say that it prevents the use of the 'new' keyword. So, I was curious to know how would one write the code below the Spring DI way?

```
private ArrayList<String> arrayMan;

public SpringDI() {
arrayMan = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

Comment: See the link below

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how this can be done using spring.

```
<bean id="arrayMan" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <ref bean="one"/>
            <ref bean="two"/>                
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

This is perfectly ok, in terms of spring DI.

If it is the default value of the variable there is nothing wrong with initializing it with `new`.

But if you still want to inject a list you can use

```
<list>
    <value>...</value>
</list>
```

Comment: What is the preferred way to do this, when working on a real spring project? I mean as a "Java Developer"?.

Comment: If it is a simple list like what you have, what you have did is right