# Is it possible to inject a bean defined with @Component as an argument to a BeanFactoryPostProcessor?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, applicationcontext

And if so which configuration is needed? Is this not recommended?

The annotated class:

```
package com.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DependantBean {

    @Resource
    DependencyBean dependencyBean; // Isn't initialized correctly

    public DependencyBean getDependencyBean() {
        return dependencyBean;
    }
}
```

The dependency bean that fails:

```
package com.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class DependencyBean {

}
```

Testcase:

```
package com.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue;

import static org.fest.assertions.Assertions.assertThat;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue.DependantBean;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = "/applicationContext.xml")
public class AppTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Resource
    private DependantBean annotatedBean;

    @Test
    public void testThatDependencyIsInjected() {
        // Fails as dependency injection of annotatedBean.dependencyBean does not work
        assertThat(annotatedBean.getDependencyBean()).isNotNull();
    }
}
```

A custom BeanFactoryPostProcessor with the "faulty" dependency:

```
package com.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class BeanFactoryPostProcessorConfiguration {

    /**
     * The {@link DependantBean} here causes the bug, can
     * {@link BeanFactoryPostProcessor} have regular beans as dependencies?
     */
    @Bean
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor(
            DependantBean dependantBean) {
        return new BeanFactoryPostProcessor() {

            public void postProcessBeanFactory(
                    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory)
                    throws BeansException {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

applicationContext.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue" />
</beans>
```

Why can't `BeanFactoryPostProcessorConfiguration` reference `DependantBean`?

The resulting `DependantBean` instance in `AppTest` is not null, i.e it's created by spring, but its dependencies (`DependencyBean`) are null. The fact that Spring doesn't complain at all leads me to believe that this is a bug within spring. Should this use-case be supported or not?

Btw, I'm using spring-*-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar
Btw 2: the code to reproduce the bug can also be found [here](https://github.com/jontejj/spring-inject-test).

Comment: There is something fishy going on in CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor. Can you switch to @Autowired annotations instead of @Resource? Does it help?

Comment: Good theory but myDependency is still null. I'm surprised that spring eats it up and just continue without even reporting a failed injection.

Comment: When it works 
`ApplicationContextAwareProcessor
AbstractApplicationContext$BeanPostProcessorChecker
ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor
CamelBeanPostProcessor
CoreNamespacePostProcessor
CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor
AbstractApplicationContext$ApplicationListenerDetector`
are registered as bean processors but when it doesn't only `ApplicationContextAwareProcessor` is registered.

Comment: Random findings now include that `testClass` is not part of `hashCode` or `equals` in `MergedContextConfiguration`

Comment: There are some non-standard post processors. So the example in the question is not complete. Are you sure you are not in jar-hell situation? Are you using Maven?

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that this code is only an extract and that this is what I've tried with to recreate the issue. There may be something else in the codebase that is causing the issue. We're using ant (much to my annoyance). What do you mean with jar-hell? That several versions of Spring is on the classpath?

Comment: I've tried to put a breakpoint in the MyClass constructor and it's only executed once.

Comment: "That several versions of Spring is on the classpath?"
Yes... I will try to reproduce this myself based on your information. Looks very strange.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30111/discussion-between-jontejj-and-pavel-horal)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to some serious debugging of spring we found out that the `DependantBean` parameter 
to `BeanFactoryPostProcessorConfiguration` caused eager initialization of other (seamingly unrelated) beans. 
But as spring was in the `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` stage the `BeanPostProcessors` weren't ready.

Reading the javadoc for [BeanFactoryPostProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanFactoryPostProcessor.html) (Thanks to @Pavel for pointing this out) explains the issue exactly:

> BeanFactoryPostProcessor may interact with and modify bean definitions, but never bean instances. 
>   Doing so may cause premature bean instantiation, violating the container and causing unintended side-effects. 
>   If bean instance interaction is required, consider implementing {@link BeanPostProcessor} instead.

The solution:

The slightly modified `applicationContext.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.stackoverflow.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue.other" />
</beans>
```

The new `bootstrapContext.xml`: (Notice that only the packages differ)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.stackoverflow.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue.bootstrap" />
</beans>
```

The new `Contexts.java`: (Notice that bootstrap is parent context to the regular applicationContext)

```
package com.stackoverflow.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.google.common.base.Supplier;
import com.google.common.base.Suppliers;

public final class Contexts
{
    private static Supplier<ApplicationContext> bootstrap = Suppliers.memoize(new Supplier<ApplicationContext>(){
        public ApplicationContext get()
        {
            return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/bootstrapContext.xml");
        }
    });

    /**
    * Context for beans that are needed before initializing of other beans.
    */
    public static ApplicationContext bootstrap()
    {
        return bootstrap.get();
    }

    private static Supplier<ApplicationContext> applicationContext = Suppliers.memoize(new Supplier<ApplicationContext>(){
        public ApplicationContext get()
        {
            return new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"/applicationContext.xml"}, bootstrap());
        }
    });

    public static ApplicationContext applicationContext()
    {
        return applicationContext.get();
    }
}
```

The `BeanFactoryPostProcessorConfiguration` without `DependantBean` as a parameter:

```
package com.stackoverflow.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue.other;

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.stackoverflow.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue.Contexts;
import com.stackoverflow.springbug.beanfactorydependencyissue.bootstrap.DependantBean;

@Configuration
public class BeanFactoryPostProcessorConfiguration
{

    /**
    * The {@link DependantBean} here caused the bug, {@link Contexts#bootstrap()} is used as a
    * workaround.
    */
    @Bean
    public static BeanFactoryPostProcessor beanFactoryPostProcessor()
    {
        final DependantBean dependantBean = Contexts.bootstrap().getBean(DependantBean.class);
        System.out.println(dependantBean.getDependencyBean());
        return new BeanFactoryPostProcessor(){
            public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException
            {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

The last thing to make it work was to move `DependantBean` and `DependencyBean` into the `bootstrap` package.
The goal was achieved to read `@Value` properties from the database. While reusing the old definitions of the beans and without duplicating the beans.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe more simpler and descriptive answer:

**Yes, it is possible to use `@Component` bean as `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` dependency.**

However every dependency of a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` will be instantiated before any `BeanPostProcessor` is active. And these include:

- `CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` - responsible for `@PostConstruct`, `@Resource` and some other annotations
- `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` - responsible for `@Autowired` and `@Value` annotations
- *...and many more...*

So tu sum it up:

**Yes, it is possible to use `@Component` bean as `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` dependency, but they can not use annotation based injection (`@Autowired`, `@Resource`, `@WebServiceRef`, ...) and other features provided by `BeanPostProcessor`s .**

---

Workaround for your example might be to create `ApplicationContext` hierarchy as you have suggested:

- Each context initializes and applies its own *post processor* infrastructure, where you still can reference dependencies from parent contexts.

---

Other approaches might be (which I would prefer):

- Use `BeanFactoryAware` interface on your `@Component` bean and pull your dependency yourself (as Spring will not inject it).
- Define beans connected with `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s within context configuration `XML` or `@Configuration` (i.e. don't use `@Component` for these beans).

Comment: Great suggestions. The parent application context solution worked like a charm as we could reuse existing bean definitions. If the project weren't so big I might have gone with your suggestions though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give an id to your component like this

```
 @Component("myClass")
 public class MyClass implements MyInterface
  {
   @Resource
   private MyDependency myDependency; //Isn't initialized correctly when listOfMyClassBeans references myClass

   //Implementation skipped for brevity's sake...
  }
```

and then use the reference

```
 <ref bean="myClass">
```

Comment: Nice touch that @NullPointerException answers a question about a NullPointerException:)

Comment: Sadly it didn't help with an id.

Comment: The issue seems to be that I can reference xml defined beans with @Resource but not vice-versa if there's a circular dependency.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace ?

Comment: It's when I access myClass.myDependency.someMethod() the issue appears. So spring doesn't complain, it just creates an empty class where no member variable is injected. So I'm afraid the stacktrace in this case would be useless.

Comment: That means the spring has resolved the reference to the bean created by annotation otherwise the context would have complained

Answer (score 0):

Try using Spring Util name space and specify value-type. Refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring)

Comment: Sure a better typed list is better but why would that solve this issue? The bean is referenced to with "myClass" which isn't ambiguous.