# How can I map property file items to Map object in Spring Application Context xml?

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, properties

I have a property file as such

```
com.country.<COUNTRY>=<values comma seperated>
```

For example:

```
com.country.UK=100,200
com.country.US=10,20
```

Now in future there can be many others country entries added
Can I get these values in to a `Map<String,List<Integer>>` in spring application context xml via propertyPlaceHolder?

Answer (score 1):

You can use spring util:
 Don't forget to import scheme, use util:map and util:list to construct any structure you want. It's ok to use ref-ids as values:

```
<beans  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd">

<util:map id="map1" map-class="java.util.HashMap">
    <entry key="smthgkey" value="smthvalue"/>
</util:map>

<util:list id="list1" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <value>val1</value>
</util:list>
```

Alternative way is to create bean with necessary structure, but I never used this way. You can find examples here: [How to define a List bean in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring)

Comment: but how to get my dynamic property name and values mapped?

Comment: once properties were loaded, the only way I know to reload them is to [refresh](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/context/support/AbstractApplicationContext.html#refresh%28%29)  context. Maybe it is better to create custom method for reloading your properties directly from file (or db) without redundant context manipulations.