# How to create a list filled with instances of a prototype bean using annotations?

Tags: java, spring

From this Q/A: [How to define a List bean in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2416056/1065197) I know I can define a `List<Foo> fooList` filled with `Foo` bean instances but using XML configuration. Here's an example:

```
public interface Foo {
    //methods here...
    void fooMethod();
}

@Service("foo")
@Scope("prototype")
public class FooImpl implements Foo {
    //fields and methods...
    @Override
    public void fooMethod() {
        //...
    }
}

@Service("fooCache")
@Scope
public class FooCacheImpl implements Foo {
    //fields and methods...
    @Override
    public void fooMethod() {
        //retrieves data from some cache
        //...
    }
}

@Service("fooWS")
@Scope("prototype")
public class FooWSImpl implements Foo {
    //fields and methods...
    @Override
    public void fooMethod() {
        //retrieves data from web service
        //...
    }
}
```

I can configure a client through XML:

```xml
<bean id="fooClient" class="some.package.FooClient">
    <property name="fooList">
        <list>
            <bean ... /> <!-- This may be fooImpl -->
            <bean ... /> <!-- This may be fooCacheImpl -->
            <bean ... /> <!-- This may be fooWSImpl -->
            <!-- I can have more beans here -->
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I want to know if this can be done with annotations only, no need to define the bean through XML. Something like this:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class FooClient {
    //which annotation(s) to use here to fill this list with FooImpl instances?
    //I understand that if I have two implementations of Foo I may use a @Qualifier
    //or use another list to note the different implementations.
    private List<Foo> fooList;

    public void bar() {
        for (Foo foo : fooList) {
            foo.fooMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

I think it would be better a solution that doesn't involve injecting the `ApplicationContext` nor the `BeanFactory` so `FooClient` is not tightly coupled to Spring classes. Also, for my case, I cannot use any Java EE classes like `javax.inject.Provider` as shown in this blog post: [Spring 2.5.x+3.0.x: Create prototype instances from code](http://benkiew.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/spring-2-5-x-create-prototype-instances-from-code/).

Comment: do you want to create many of the same bean in the list?

Comment: you could create many annotated setter injections that each take the bean of the type and they add the bean to the encapsulated list

Comment: And how many instances of the prototype shall your List have?

Comment: I agree it's not a very good way of doing it. For an alternative see my answer using a factory bean - might work better ;-)

Comment: What about a method injection? A method which returns an instance of the bean on each call, and then initialize the List in another step by calling the injected method as many times as you like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a Factory Bean?

I know you mentioned you did not want to be too coupled to spring - with a factory bean your bean containing the list is not so coupled - just your factory is.

Something like

```
@Component("fooList")
class ListFactory<List<Foo>> implements FactoryBean, ApplicationContextAware {

     ApplicationContext context;
     public List<Foo>> getObject() {
           List<Foo> list = new ArrayList();
           list.add(context.getBean("foo");
           list.add(context.getBean("foo");
           return list;
     }

     public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) {
             this.context = context;
     }

     public boolean isSingleton() {
           return false;
     }
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype")
class FooClient {

    @Inject
    @Named("footList")
    private List<Foo> fooList;

    public void bar() {
        for (Foo foo : fooList) {
            foo.fooMethod();
        }
    }
}
```

Haven't tried it myself, or had the scenario where I've needed it so I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: With the details you've given us, OP, I think this is the right solution. Just keep in mind that if you later create new `Foo` beans, those won't be added to `FooClient` list.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing it in the code directly, then I think using the `PostConstruct` annotation would be the way to go:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
public class FooClient {

....

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws Exception {
        fooList = new ArrayList<Foo>();
        fooList.add(new FooImpl());
    }
```

I think using this approach would be more flexible, since I think you will struggle with annotations only if the `FooImpl` objects themselves require additional configuration.

Comment: The fact is they do, but I have an `init` method to handle that (until I get a better idea).

Answer (score 0):

That's a limitation (or feature) of `prototype` scope. [The docs say this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype)

> In contrast to the other scopes, Spring does not manage the complete
>   lifecycle of a prototype bean: the container instantiates, configures,
>   and otherwise assembles a prototype object, and hands it to the
>   client, with no further record of that prototype instance.

So after Spring hands it off to you, it doesn't keep any reference to it and therefore cannot autowire any of them into your `fooList`. If you did add `@Autowired`

```
@Autowired 
private List<Foo> fooList;
```

it would just create a new `FooImpl` object and autowire that as the single element in your `List`.

If you're trying to keep a reference of all the `Foo` instances created, you'll most likely have to do it yourself.

Comment: So I would need a kind of factory method that returns a new instance of the bean I want/need upon *manual* requests. Is there any good approach that doesn't involve a XML configuration nor the direct usage of `BeanFactory` in my class?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza The issue is that both your components are `prototype` beans, so any time you request either, you'll get a new instance. Can you go into more detail about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to fill a list of my `Foo` interface with prototype beans. As simple as that. This is part of a solution to enhance a process. In order to add multiple threads to the solution, I must create more instances of `Foo`, one per thread, to avoid problems of multiple threads accessing the same resources (that explains the usage of prototype scopes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use method injection as this:

```
public class PrototypeClient {

    protected abstract PrototypeBean createPrototype();

    private List<PrototypeBean> createPrototypeList() {
        int listSize = calculateListSize();

        List<Prototype> result = new ArrayList<Prototype(listSize);

        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++) {
            result.add(createPrototype());
        }
        return result;
    } 

    private int calculateListSize() {
       // do your stuff here
    }

    // ...
}
```

and have an Spring config as:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"       
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="prototypeBean"
          class="fully.qualified.class.name.of.Prototype"
          scope="prototype" />

    <bean id="prototyeClient"
          class="fully.qualified.class.name.of.PrototypeClient">
         <lookup-method name="createPrototype" bean="prototypeBean"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```