# BeanCreationException in spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

I am getting an `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException` in my spring controller as I use ResponseList bean.

```
Error creating bean with name 'responseList' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: 1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean 'responseList' (hint: specify index/type/name arguments for simple parameters to avoid type ambiguities)
```

Here is the context part:

```
<bean id="response" class="com.form.response.Response" scope="prototype"></bean>    
    <bean id="myController" class="com.controllers.MyController" scope="prototype">
            <property name="response" ref="response"></property>
            <property name="responseList" ref="responseList"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="responseList" class="carey.form.response.ResponseList">
            <constructor-arg type="java.util.List">
                <list>
                   <ref bean="response"/>
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Here is the Bean:

```
package com.form.response;

import java.util.List;

public class ResponseList {

    public ResponseList() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private List<Response> responseList;

    public List<Response> getResponseList() {
        return responseList;
    }

    public void setResponseList(List<Response> responseList) {
        this.responseList = responseList;
    }

}
```

Can anyone please correct what I am missing here?

Comment: Is there a bean defined in your xml with `id="response"`

Comment: @onepotato yes, I mentioned in edit now

Comment: You don't have a constructor that accepts `java.util.List` as parameter. Also, class name defined in the xml is `carey.form.response.ResponseList` where as in your java class it is `com.form.response.ResponseList`

Comment: I found my answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring

Comment: @onepotato sorry that carey thing was a typo I corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using constructor injection

```
<bean id="response" class="com.form.response.Response" scope="prototype"></bean>    
    <bean id="myController" class="com.controllers.MyController" scope="prototype">
            <property name="response" ref="response"></property>
            <property name="responseList" ref="responseList"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="responseList" class="carey.form.response.ResponseList">
            <constructor-arg type="java.util.List">
                <list>
                   <ref bean="response"/>
                </list>
            </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

then bean like

```
package com.form.response;

import java.util.List;

public class ResponseList {

    public ResponseList(List<Response> responseList) {
           this.responseList=responseList;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    private List<Response> responseList;

    public List<Response> getResponseList() {
        return responseList;
    }

    public void setResponseList(List<Response> responseList) {
        this.responseList = responseList;
    }

}
```

and if setter injection

```
<bean id="response" class="com.form.response.Response" scope="prototype"></bean>    
    <bean id="myController" class="com.controllers.MyController" scope="prototype">
            <property name="response" ref="response"></property>
            <property name="responseList" ref="responseList"></property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="responseList" class="carey.form.response.ResponseList">
            <property type="java.util.List">
                <list>
                   <ref bean="response"/>
                </list>
            </property>
    </bean>
```

then bean like

```
public class ResponseList {

    public ResponseList() {
    }

    private List<Response> responseList;

    public List<Response> getResponseList() {
        return responseList;
    }

    public void setResponseList(List<Response> responseList) {
        this.responseList = responseList;
    }

}
```

Comment: So the `responseList` bean will include `response` bean object state automatically?

Comment: Now I am getting

`org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'com.form.response.ResponseList' to required type 'java.util.List' for property 'responseList'`

Comment: I found my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring

Comment: yes that is using property di you can do same with constructor di

as you did in your code but your java class has no costructor with list argument 
that's why you get `1 constructor arguments specified but no matching constructor found in bean`

Comment: Okay, thanks for the answer. I was little weak in this place.

Answer (score 1):

The exception says, `Error creating bean with name 'responseList' defined in ServletContext resource`,
Spring not getting a argument-ed constructor in ResponseList bean..

```
<bean id="responseList" class="carey.form.response.ResponseList">
        <constructor-arg type="java.util.List">
            <list>
               <ref bean="response"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Replace your no-arg constructor from

```
public ResponseList() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

with

```
public ResponseList(List<Response> responseList){
    this.responseList = responseList;
}
```