# how to remove class cast exception in spring java?

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have written code that uses spring util namespace.
I have a class named City with the following properties:

```
private List<String> name;
private List<String> state;
private List<Integer> population;
//setter and getter methods go here ...
```

and I configured the application context as:

```
<util:list id="cities" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
    p:name="chennai" p:state="tamilnadu" p:population="2000000"/>
  <bean class="com.example2.City"
        p:name="bang" p:state="karnataka" p:population="3000000"/>
</util:list>
```

When I run the application it gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.example2.City

Will someone help me out? Thanks.

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a wrong `City` class defined. Why does a City have to have a list of names and a list of population numbers ?

I think `City` should look more like:

```
public class City {
   private String name;

   private String state;

   private String population;

   //accessors
}
```

In this case, the `<util:list>` should look like:

```
<util:list id="cities" list-class="java.util.ArrayList">
  <bean class="com.example2.City"
        p:name="bang" 
        p:state="karnataka" 
        p:population="3000000"/>
  <bean class="com.example2.City"
        p:name="chennai" 
        p:state="tamilnadu" 
        p:population="2000000"/>
</util:list>
```

and you will have a list of two *cities*.