# creating spring list as bean in XML

Tags: java, xml, spring

I want to create a list of beans with an ID so that I can use ApplicationContext.getBean() to retrieve it into my standalone application.

I created the list this way:

```
<list id="airMessageHandlers">
    <bean id="signInResultHandler" class="com.blah.AirMessageHandler"/>
</list>
```

Then I want to do

getBean("airMessageHandlers");

The problem is that when I bring in the XML file, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 18 in XML document from class path resource [conf/portserver.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 37; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'list'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:398)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:335)
```

...
    Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 37; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'list'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean, WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"], "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:134)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:437)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:368)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:325)
 ...

I couldn't find an example of a list as a stand alone bean and I'm wondering if that is a problem, but the DTD looks fine for this.

Comment: have you seen http://stackoverflow.com/a/2416145/217324 ?

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring

Comment: @NathanHughes Hello, old friend. I did see that, but didn't think it applied to me. Turns out it does. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was:

```
<util:list id="airMessageHandlers">
    <ref bean="signInResultHandler"/>
</util:list>

<bean id="signInResultHandler" class="com.blah.AirMessageHandler"/>
```