# spring batch ItemProcessorAdapter how to pass multiple argument to targetMethod?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Below is my ItemProcessor bean, I am implementing ItemProcessor interface. It works fine but

```
<beans:bean id="myItemProcessor"
        class="com.st.foundation.MyItemProcessor"
        p:id="#{jobParameters[date]}" p:type="my-type"
        scope="step" />
```

I want to combine many such beans in to single pojo and use an ItemProcessorAdapter.

```
<beans:bean id="myItemProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.adapter.ItemProcessorAdapter"
    p:targetObject-ref="myObject" p:targetMethod="myMethod"
    p:arguments="{jobParameters[date]}"  scope="step" />
```

But my targetMethod has multiple arguments (type argument along with id). How can I pass multiple arguments to the adapter  as it has only p:arguments parameter ?

I tried separating arguments by comma but it doesn't work. Getting error "target class must declare a method with matching name and parameter types".

Also I tried using

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:file="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file"
    xmlns:integration="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/file/spring-integration-file.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <util:list id="myList" value-type="java.lang.String">
        <value>foo</value>
        <value>bar</value>
    </util:list>
```

from this [How to define a List bean in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring)

But I am getting "cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'value'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me,

```
<util:list id="myList" value-type="java.lang.String"
    scope="step">
    <beans:value>value1</beans:value>
    <beans:value>value2</beans:value>
</util:list>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`AbstractMethodInvokingDelegator.setArguments()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/adapter/AbstractMethodInvokingDelegator.html#setArguments%28java.lang.Object%5b%5d%29) accepts an array of Object as parameter; values of this array are used as parameterS so:

Try separating values by comma

`"p:arguments="{jobParameters[date]},param2,param3"`

or without p namespace facilities:

```
<property name="arguments">
  <list>
    <value>{jobParameters[date]}</value>
    <value>param2</value>
    <value>param3</value>
  </list>
</property>
```

Comment: Tried separating by comma but it doesn't work. Getting error  "target class must declare a method with matching name and parameter types"

Comment: You are missing a # before `{jobParameters[date]}` in `myItemProcessor` bean