# Autowiring of a java List in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have the following Bean which I would like to have autowired in another class:

```
@Scope("job")
@Component
public class PublicCompanyHolder {

private List<File> publicCompanyList;

public List<File> getPublicCompanyList() {
return publicCompanyList;
}

public void setPublicCompanyList(List<File> publicCompanyList) {
this.publicCompanyList = publicCompanyList;
}

}
```

My Spring config looks like :

```
 <bean id="publicCompanyHolder" class="com.sample.bean.PublicCompanyHolder" >   
        <property name="publicCompanyList" ref="publicCompanyList" />
     </bean>
      <bean id="publicCompanyList" class="java.util.List" />
```

Is this the right way to do it.In another class by simply saying:

```
@Autowired
    private PublicCompanyHolder publicCompanyHolder;
```

I would like to use the class.Please let me know.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? What happened when you tried it?

Comment: I was getting the following error - Error creating bean with name 'publicCompanyHolder' defined in class path resource [applicationBatchContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'publicCompanyList' while setting bean property 'publicCompanyList'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'publicCompanyList' defined in class path resource [applicationBatchContext.xml]: .

Comment: I was able to fix this.There were two issues.One was a class needed to be used instead of an interface(List).Second,scanning of the packages needed to be enabled in the spring config file.

Answer (score -1):

java.util.List is the interface. You need to give implementation.

```
<bean id="publicCompanyList" class="java.util.List" />
```

You can do like below

[How to define a List bean in Spring?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring)

Comment: Thanks @Sumit.I will look at the link.