# Populate <list> tag in spring with MANY beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
<util:list id="messageUtilList">
    <ref bean="stringMessage01"/>
    <ref bean="stringMessage02"/>
    ....more then a million elements must be stored in that list

</util:list>
```

Is there any solution for binding between for example some variable `List<Obj> messages` in code and  `<list>` tag in SPRING xml

Something like

```
 <util:list id="messageUtilList">
    <ref messages/>
</util:list>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define a List bean in Spring?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a bean definition where you inject the list messageUtilList

```
bean id="myListConsumerBean" class="ListConsumerClass"
```

1. Create an interface ListGenerator

   ```
   public interface ListGenerator<T> {
       public List<T> generateList();
   }
   ```
2. Create your list producer that builds the list for million of messages (Replace String with the actual message Class)

   ```
   public class MyListGenerator implements ListGenerator<String> {

    @Override
    public List<String> generateList() {

      List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

       ... code to populate list ...
       return myList;
     }
   }
   ```
3. Modify your ListConsumerClass to accept a ListGenerator (rather than a List)
4. Adjust the Spring bean wiring to create a bean definition for MyListGenerator , and inject that into your ListConsumerClass (instead of creating and injecting the util:list).  The generateList() method will contain the millions of elements.