# How to create a arraylist of type string bean with a factory method return

Tags: java, spring, arraylist

I have a method in a class that returns a ArrayList, and I want to use this return to create a bean like this:

```
<bean id="myList" factory-bean="myClass" factory-method="getMyList" class="java.util.ArrayList">
    <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String">
        <util:constant static-field="com.myapp.searchapp.MY_VALUE"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

But when I try to ref this bean from another bean IntelliJ complains that:

```
Bean must be one of these types: java.lang.String or java.util.ArrayList<java.lang.String> less... (Ctrl+F1) 
Checks value types for Spring injections (properties & constructor arguments)
```

What exactly am I doing wrong here?

Comment: please also show us (the constructor and the `getMyList` method of) `myClass`....i assume some confusion there.

Comment: ..."factory-method" MUST take NO arguments, `myClass` should have a 1-string-costructor (if really needed...and the only real way to pass parameters to "factory-method"), and should be declared (& also "constructored") ...in some visible spring context....prior to `myList`...

Answer (score 0):

..as mentioned in comment, you must ensure the "factory-method" takes no arguments:

```
package foo.bar;
...
public class MyClass {
  ...
  public List<String> getMyList() {
    //maybe rather a copy than the original ;)
    return daList;
  }
...
```

Given e.g. a 1-String constuctor:

```
...
  public MyClass(String one) {
    daList = new ArrayList<>();
    daList.add(one); 
  }
...
}
```

...and a the constant String `com.myapp.searchapp.MY_VALUE`
you could wire it all like:

```
<bean id="myClass" class="foo.bar.MyClass">
  <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String">
      <util:constant static-field="com.myapp.searchapp.MY_VALUE" />
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- and... -->
<bean id="myList" factory-bean="myClass" factory-method="getMyList" />
```

[Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/dependency-injection-with-factory-method) - the top googl-hit on "spring factory method"

... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/) - a popular, related & maybe helpful question.