# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException with list of string - pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, list, pom.xml

I have problem with NoSuchBeanDefinitionException.

```
@Component
public class Monitor {

    private List<String> urlsToCheckState;

    @Autowired
    ServerConfig config; 

    public Monitor(config config, List<String> urlsToCheckState){
       urlsToCheckState.add("state1");
    }
```

I understand that Spring can not find Bean which return list of String. I was looking for solution but coudn't find anything which solve my problem. 
Here is my error.

> Error creating bean with name 'Monitor' defined in file [C:\Users]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have dependencies injected at construction you need to have your constructor marked with the @Autowired annoation like below.

```
@Autowired
Monitor(List<String> urlsToCheckState){
   this.urlsToCheckState = urlsToCheckState;
}
```

Of course before injection you must create instance of bean urlsToCheckState.

Comment: How to do it? It is just simple list of strings

Comment: You can do this that way: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416056/how-to-define-a-list-bean-in-spring

Comment: Should I add it to pom.xml?

Comment: You should add it to your configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not used @Autowired on urlsToCheckState. You have to inject it using constructor injection.

Inside your component create a constructor as below:-

```
Monitor(List<String> urlsToCheckState){
   this.urlsToCheckState = urlsToCheckState;
}
```

This way you would be able to inject using constructor.

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help - `Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [Monitor]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Monitor.<init>()` then I added deafult constructor and have another exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: null
 at Monitor.(Monitor.java:135) ~[classes/:na]`

Comment: okay! Have you declared List<String> urlsToCheckState as a bean anywhere in a config file. Because looks like you haven't declared a bean anywhere?

Comment: I did not. When I was looking for an answer I saw some information that I should declared List of String in config file but I do know how and where should I make it